# Bloomberg alternatives for fixed income data

Tags: data, bloomberg, reuters

I am looking for a (hopefully significantly cheaper) alternative to bloomberg - primarily for fixed income data. Perhaps some survice that has a more modular fee structure (so that I only have to pay for more or less what I need)

> It should at least provide:
>
> - Quotes for swaptions and caps (different trikes, tenors etc.)  Curves
> - swap-curves etc

**Motivation:**
I hardly ever work with equity data and mostly need fixed income quotes to calibrate my models etc. Unfortunately my department does not have it's own terminal (due to budgetary reasons) and I always have to bum data off some co-worker (or use his/her terminal - mostly late at night). My reasoning: if I can show a viable and cheap Bloomberg alternative for the data I actually need, my superiors might reconsider.

Answer (score 5):

Macrobond, a swedish company might be something to consider.

http://www.macrobond.com/

Answer (score 4):

CME group has free [Swap curves](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc/irs-curve-data.html). It also seems that they have quotes on the [product feature page](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc/). Hope this works for you, -if it does, maybe you can comment about the costs when you find out. Thanks.

Comment: hmm I don't really get their site yet but it seems it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Reuters is making a huge push with their `Eikon` terminals.  I think their prices are under NDA but you can often get one at a big discount to the $1700/month the `Bloomberg` charges and they are starting to close the feature gap.

You'll still need to pay the market data fees if you want real time quotes, but those fees can often be in the low 100/month range if you only need a few product categories.

Comment: Oh yes, I would second this too. I looked at it a while ago and it has stuff that I wish Bloomberg had out of the box (e.g., carry and roll for bonds, etc.)

Comment: this is some helpful information - thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the buy-side, you could also ask whether any of your counter parties may have what you need. For example, when it comes to fixed income data, Barclays Live and Morgan Markets (free to clients) may very well be better.

Comment: this is actually quite a good idea - should be cheaper than getting my own terminal. However I will still be quite inflexible and will depend on other

Answer (score 1):

The DTCC provides a free near-real-time swap activity here:
https://rtdata.dtcc.com/gtr/dashboard.do

You can subscribe to this service via RSS Feeds and mine it as needed.  Swap trades must be reported by the sell side, so you can see near-real-time activity as it occurs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.money.net/ is what I like to use it can be used in your browser and they have a 14 day trial to see if you like it.

Its relatively cheap and nice to use.